# Why can't I use an inherited, protected generic type alias?

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-alias

This doesn't work:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
protected:
    using Z = T*;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(Z) {}
};
```

Compiler says:

```
test.cpp:10:7: error: unknown type name 'Z'
    B(Z) {}
```

However this works:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
protected:
    using Z = T*;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B(typename A<T>::Z) {}
};
```

as well as this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
protected:
    using Z = T*;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<int> {
public:
    B(Z) {}
};
```

Why?

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between the second and third code blocks?

Comment: @Brian Wrong paste; fixed. Thanks.